# Getting vlc to start network stream on boot (if stream is up) and monitor stream status in case it goes down

Tags: vlc

I've written a script that first checks whether a local network stream is up, then if this is the case it will start vlc. It will then keep monitoring the stream, if it goes down it will close vlc and wait for the stream to return before restarting vlc (see below).

If I run the script manually this works.

I'd like this script to run automatically on startup (using Raspbian). The issue I seem to be having is that regardless of how I get the script to run on startup I see that it's briefly connecting to the network stream but it isn't opening vlc (at least not visibly on the desktop).

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

# Remove previous test stream grab
rm /home/pi/snapshot.png

myip="192.168.0.67"

STATUS=0
while [  $STATUS == 0 ]; do

    # Test stream by taking image grab
    ffmpeg -i rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp -frames 1 /home/pi/snapshot.png

    # Check to see if image grab has worked
    file="/home/pi/snapshot.png"
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        echo "$file found."
        # Start stream if up
        vlc rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp --fullscreen &

        STATUS_INNER=0
        while [  $STATUS_INNER == 0 ]; do
            rm /home/pi/snapshot.png
            ffmpeg -i rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp -frames 1 /home/pi/snapshot.png
            if [ -f "$file" ]
            then
                # Do nothing
                echo "Keep playing."
                sleep 10
            else
                echo "Stream stopped, trying to restart."
                pkill vlc
                STATUS_INNER=1
            fi
        done
        # STATUS=1
    else
        echo "$file not found."
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

Currently trying to run using /etc/rc.local as below

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exec 1>/tmp/rc.local.log 2>&1  # send stdout and stderr from rc.local to a log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh

exit 0
```

Comment: How are you running this on startup?

Comment: I tried a few ways: adding to init.d, editing /home/pi/.bashrc and editing /etc/rc.local (no guarantee that I did these correctly).

Comment: Try adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to the start of the script. Try launching the script from /etc/rc.local with the command `sudo -u pi bash myscript.sh`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question above with the most up to date script and a copy of /etc/rc.local. I had noticed that when I was doing the screengrab it had a relative path and the check to see if screengrab had worked was absolute. But even with this fixed it still doesn't work. I can see that snapshot.png is being created and removed over and over, so the script is running.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159544 suggests starting the script in a screen session to catch any output. http://pi.bek.no/internetRadio/ suggests that VLC will refuse to run as root, and currently your rc.local script does run as root. Try changing `/home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh` to `sudo -u pi bash /home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for the continued support. Sorry, I should have said that I'd already tried that. But the script didn't get very far. Output of rc.local > https://pastebin.com/i8CzxC5w

Comment: In that output ffmpeg is never connecting to a network stream: "Network is unreachable". It looks like it's not auto-connecting to your network? Is your WiFi/Ethernet correctly configured? Can you verify running your script once logged in works OK?

Comment: Sorry, in that last paste is seems that the camera server went down (probably due to all of the connecting/disconnecting). Try this https://pastebin.com/pkKYWSb9

Comment: Yes, if I manually run ./vlc_autorun.sh from the terminal I get the desired behaviour.

Comment: The output doesn't ever say "/home/pi/snapshot.png found" so it looks like the test for if the file exists isn't working properly. If you comment out the if/else when you know the stream works, does at least the VLC bit work OK? I have no idea why the `[ -e "$file" ]` doesn't work, but I'd try replacing it with `ls /home/pi | grep snapshot > /dev/null` and then `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]` instead to check the return code from grep, which should only be 1 if the file is found.

Comment: Thanks, I'm away at the moment. I'll try this when I can next week and get back to you.

Comment: Having come back to this, it actually seems to work without having made any real changes since I looked at it a few weeks ago (see solution). I must have done something dumb when testing before. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works! I'm not really sure which change solved it, the only changes in the scripts below are minor tweaks that shouldn't actually change anything to that which I posted last time.

The only thing I can imagine is that when I first tried changing the command in /etc/rc.local to `sudo -u pi bash /home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh` that this coincided with when the stream server crashed and this was in fact the solution i needed?

In any case, massive thanks to Fred for the pointers that got me on the right path. This should now work as a completely unmanned client which loads up a network stream if it's available, waits and periodically checks if it isn't available, and gracefully tries to re-establish a connection if it loses the feed at any point. Hope it's a help to someone else.

/home/pi/vlc_autorun.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0

# Remove previous test stream grab
rm /home/pi/snapshot.png

myip="192.168.0.67"

STATUS=0
STATUS_INNER=0
while [  $STATUS == 0 ]; do

# Test stream by taking image grab
ffmpeg -i rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp -frames 1 /home/pi/snapshot.png

# Check to see if image grab has worked
file="/home/pi/snapshot.png"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
    # Start stream if up
    vlc rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp --fullscreen &

    STATUS_INNER=0
    while [  $STATUS_INNER == 0 ]; do
        rm /home/pi/snapshot.png
        ffmpeg -i rtsp://$myip:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp -frames 1 /home/pi/snapshot.png
        if [ -f "$file" ]
        then
            # Do nothing
            echo "Keep playing."
            sleep 10
        else
            echo "Stream stopped, trying to restart."
            pkill vlc
            STATUS_INNER=1
        fi
    done
    # STATUS=1
else
    echo "$file not found."
    sleep 5
fi
done
```

/etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exec 1>/tmp/rc.local.log 2>&1  # send stdout and stderr from rc.local to a log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#/home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh
#lxterminal -e "/home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh"
sudo -u pi bash /home/pi/./vlc_autorun.sh

exit 0
```